# Simple Moving Average in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Is there way how to calculate a Simple Moving Average in XSLT 2.0? For example I will have a XML document where will be 100 values, but some function (SMA) after XSLT gives me just 50 values as output.

Thanks for all your ideas

EDIT

I added some example, as you can see I have XML document, where I have for every month a price of brand samsung. Now I would like to have just 2 values for price (for 5th month and 10th month as you can see on the picture below).

Same principle like here
http://www.dummies.com/personal-finance/investing/stocks-trading/how-to-calculate-simple-moving-average-in-trading

Here is some XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trade>
    <phone month="1" brand="samsung">
        <price>1000</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="2" brand="samsung">
        <price>890</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="3" brand="samsung">
        <price>870</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="4" brand="samsung">
        <price>950</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="5" brand="samsung">
        <price>920</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="6" brand="samsung">
        <price>930</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="7" brand="samsung">
        <price>870</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="8" brand="samsung">
        <price>830</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="9" brand="samsung">
        <price>910</price>
    </phone>
    <phone month="10" brand="samsung">
        <price>950</price>
    </phone>
</trade>
```

Here is wanted result

```
Brand samsung
month  price
  5      avg(price[1] to price[9])
 10      avg(price[2] to price[10])
```

[image: SMA with 5 period]

Comment: There's bound to be a way, but... woah, xslt doesn't sound like the right tool for the job!  :-o

Comment: Yes I know, but I have to do it with XSLT so if you know how to do this please help me.

Comment: Are you outputting to HTML for web display? If so, why not embed some JavaScript for this into your XSLT template? It would still be scary, but it might be slightly saner code than trying to do this kind of stats directly in XSLT.

Comment: It sounds good, output after XSLT is HTML, but i don`t have any idea how to do it with javascript. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Spudley what on earth makes you think that XSLT isn't well suited to this job?

Comment: Why do you relate month 5 to the average of the first nine prices? Shouldn't that be month 9? It seems you can compute your pseudo syntax `avg(price[1] to price[9])` as `avg(//price[position() = 1 to 9])` and `avg(price[2] to price[10])` as `avg(//price[position() = 2 to 10])` in XPath 2 or later.

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake, but yeah you understand me right. In question there is a link to SMA, is possible to do a template or function which will do this algorithm like there. There is 21 values and date for it, after XSLT with function SMA in output will be just 13 values and date for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by recursion http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvN/1. It works fine, the result is like in the link in question. But one more thing did not work and it is if samples do not sorted by default by date. So if samples are randomly sorted, the result is not correct. How to sort the samples by date and then use the SMA?

Comment: `//sample` gives you the unsorted sequence of sample elements, with `<xsl:variable name="sorted-samples" as="element(sample)*"><xsl:perform-sort select="//sample"><xsl:sort select="xs:integer(substring-after(substring-after(@date, '/''), '/)"/><xsl:sort select="xs:integer(substring-before(@date, '/'))"/><xsl:sort select="xs:integer(substring-before(substring-after('/', @date), '/'))"/></xsl:perform-sort></xsl:variable>` you get a sorted sequence and can pass that and use that for your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is for each item, calculate the average of the last 50 values:

```
<xsl:template match="trade">
  <sma50>
   <xsl:value-of select="avg((@price, 
                   preceding-sibling::trade[position() lt 50]/@price))"/>
  </sma50>
</xsl:template>
```

This of course involves some redundant computation for every item. If you want to avoid this redundant computation, it's possible, but the code will be quite a bit trickier. The rolling average for the Nth item (N>50) is the rolling average for the (N-1)th item plus the difference between the Nth value and the (N-50)th value divided by 50. So you could do the calculation with sibling recursion, where after processing one item, you then call a template to process its immediate following sibling, passing the current rolling average as a parameter. But I very much doubt that the performance gain is worth the extra hassle.

You have updated the question: in the revised version, it doesn't seem like a moving average, but more like a periodic average. If you want to report the average for each group of 5 consecutive months, you can simply do:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="trade/phone" group-adjacent="@month idiv 5">
  <month nr="{current-group()[last()]/@month}" 
         avg-price="{avg(current-group()/@price)}"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: @michaelhkay I added to question more information and also example. I s there way write a stylesheet or function (with parameters-period) for it? Thank you a lot

Comment: Yes, but the average have to be in relationship with previous values right? So if I want from 10 values just 2 values, I will do a one average for value[1] to value[9] and second average for value[2] to value[10]. In result I will have 2 average with relationship with previous values. So how should a template look like?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having great trouble seeing how you decide which items to include in each of your averages. However, if you could express the rule clearly in English then it would be very easy to translate it to XSLT.

Comment: I apologize for my English, I will try my best. The reason is as I said before, I can have an XML document that can contain thousands, ten thousand or more values. I want to make XSLT for this XML document and output will be HTML document. So, after XSLT, I only want for example 100 values from an XML document because the WEB browser can crash to display as many values (thousand, ten thousand, ...). That's why I want to use SMA, so the values will be inferior to the result, but they will be in a relationship.

Comment: If month 5 shows an average for months 1 to 9, and month 10 shows an average for months 2 to 10, then what should month 15 show?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand right. Here is how to calculate SMA9 [link] (http://www.dummies.com/personal-finance/investing/stocks-trading/how-to-calculate-simple-moving-average-in-trading/) - so the first average is calculated from position 1 to 9 divide by 9. Then is average from 2 to 10 divide 9 and so on to end. The result is just 13 values from 21 - it is same way like my question. I just want a function/template which will calculate this principle if it is even possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I would have been useful to cite that in the original question (financial traders aren't the only people to use moving averages...)

Comment: I added a reference to question. So it is possible so it with XSLT please?